# Access an unknown Firebase path

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

First of all will be easier if you check the Firebase realtime database image:

[image: Firebase database]

So with my code I create some "practicas" with an id (152648... in this case) and then, inside that object I create a list of "grupos" (groups). The problem comes here, to do this I use .push(), so Firebase creates a list inside that firebase main node, but the thing is that the 'key' it uses is random, so then, I want to access to the last step called "alumnos", but as I don't know the previous key I can't access there. I tried to use an ID to push the object but it adds the ID and then the key.

**My code:**

```
//don't take care about what is values[], grupoList[] and so on
//I just take values from a checkbox on the HTML and I send them to the 'grupo' value of the object 'practica'
addGroup(){
 let y=0;
 for(let i=0; i<this.values.length; i++){
   if(this.values[i] == true){
     this.grupoList[y] = this.profiles[i];
     y++;
   }
 }
 this.grupo.alumnos = this.grupoList;
 this.practica.grupo = this.grupo;
 this.practicaService.anyadirGrupos(this.practica);
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(VerGruposPage, {'data': this.practica});
}
```

**PracticaService:**

```
//Here is where I work with firebase adding the 'grupo'
public anyadirGrupos(practica){
    this.afDB.database.ref('practicas/' + practica.id + '/grupos/').push(practica.grupo);
}

//to access the node 'alumnos' (it doesn't work)
public getAlumnos(practica){
    return this.afDB.list('practicas/' + practica.id +'/grupos/' + '../alumnos/')
}
```

Any idea to access to the last step without knowing the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different possible approaches:

**1/ Write the "sub-grupos" without an extra key**

Which means having a database structure like this:

```
- practicas
   -idPracticas
     -grupos
        -alumnos
           -0 ....
           -1 ......
        -anotherGroupName
           -0 ....
           -1 ......
```

To do that you should use `set()` instead of `push()`

**2/ Keep your structure and loop over the different child nodes**

```
db.ref('practicas/' + practica.id + '/grupos/').orderByKey().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val());
            console.log(childSnapshot.val().alumnos[0]);    
            console.log(childSnapshot.val().alumnos[1]);    
        });
  });
```

Comment: The problem of using set() is that if I add another group it will overwrite the existing one and I want to create some groups for every 'practica'.

Comment: Don't really understand #2 but will try it hahaha

Comment: Hello Eric, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: didn't really understand #2 but I think I found a way, just taking everything and using for loops

Comment: #2 is actually the loop solution, so I guess it should s similar to what you do.